# In Ruby on Rails what should be the flow for executing rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I am new in Ruby on Rails, I have little bit of confusion in Ruby on rails application. I have done all these things.

routes.rb

```
Recruitment::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'hr/internal_employee_page', controller: 'hr', action: 'internal_employee_page'
  get 'hr/permanent_consultant_page' => 'hr#permanent_consultant_page', as: :permanent_consultant_page
end
```

hr_controller.rb

```
class HrController < ApplicationController

  def internal_employee_page
    @employees = OfferLetter.all
    # render :text => @employees.inspect        
  end

  def employee_details
    @employees = OfferLetter.all
  end
end
```

_hr_page.html.erb

```
<%= render 'hr/dashboard'%> <%= render 'hr/internal_employee_page'%>
```

_internal_employee_page.html.erb

```
<div id="job_details">
    <%= render "hr/employee_details" %>
</div>
```

_employee_details.html.erb

```
<% @employees.each do |emp| %>
    <h3> Employee Name : <%= emp.full_name %> </h3>
<% end %>
```

Then I got this error:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.
```

When I did trace, I found `hr_controller.rb` was not executing. If I comment out everything in `hr_controller.rb`, then I get the same error. So please tell me what I am doing wrong and what is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails looks for a view with the same name as the controller method. Remove the underscore from the name of the internal_employee_page.html.erb file. You use underscores for partials.

internal_employee_page.html.erb

```
<div id="job_details">
  <% @employees.each do |emp| %>
    <%= render partial: "hr/employee_details", locals: {emp: emp} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_employee_details.html.erb

```
<h3> Employee Name : <%= emp.full_name %> </h3>
```

It may be worth reading [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) regarding rendering layouts and partials.

The nil error means the active record call, OfferLetter.all, is failing. Have you set up that d/b table, run the migrations etc? Try running that command in a rails console and see what you get.

Comment: Yes, I got solution thank you so much margo. Please can you tell me, which book should i follow for learning ROR.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please 'accept' it by clicking the 'check' icon. There are loads of online resources, many people like Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. The guides I linked to are also good.

Comment: Thank you margo. Do you have facebook account, please send me friend request on facebook(/jamiit.khusvaha).